# Label text out of frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, json, tkinter, frame

I have the following issue. I created a frame with a scrollbar in tkinter. The frame has a label which takes information from a json file and it loads it there.
Here's the code:

```
    second_frame = Frame(canvas)
    
    canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor='nw')

    label = Label(second_frame, text=str(info), anchor='e', justify=LEFT)
    label.pack()
```

The problem is that when a sentence is too long, it gets out of the frame, which is weird because I thought that these labels had an automatic system to detect when it gets out of the frame. Here's an example:

[image]

The program took this text from the json file:

```
"\nThis is Matt\nIf I press enter, everything is fine.\nBut if I don't enter and make this sentence too long, the text will get out of the frame.\n"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to make the canvas+frame expand to fit the text or do you want to add a word wrap?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain, this canvas is not resized, it's just its normal size. The width that I chose is 400 by default, I will disable the option to resize it later. What I want to do is basically make the text jump line when it reaches the end of the frame's width.

Comment: That is called word wrap. It will be hard to implement dynamically but you might want to try adding `width=80` to `label = Label(...)`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by using wraplength

```
WINDOW_WIDTH = 400 # your default window size
Label(text="your long json here", wraplength=WINDOW_WIDTH - 20).pack()
```